# convert irregular 6hourly data to daily accumulated using R

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
 Date,Rain
 1979_8_9_0,8.775
 1979_8_9_6,8.775
 1979_8_9_12,8.775
 1979_8_9_18,8.775
 1979_8_10_0,0  
 1979_8_10_6,0
 1979_8_10_12,0
 1979_8_10_18,0 
 1979_8_11_0,8.025
 1979_8_12_12,0
 1979_8_12_18,0 
 1979_8_13_0,8.025
```

[1] The data is six hourly but some dates have incomplete 6 hourly data. For example, August 11 1979 has only one value at 00H. I would like to get the daily accumulated from this kind of data using R. Any suggestion on how to do this easily in R?

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform your data to dates very easily with:

```
dat$Date <- as.Date(strptime(dat$Date, '%Y_%m_%d_%H'))
```

After that you should aggregate with:

```
aggregate(Rain ~ Date, dat, sum)
```

The result:

```
        Date   Rain
1 1979-08-09 35.100
2 1979-08-10  0.000
3 1979-08-11  8.025
4 1979-08-12  0.000
5 1979-08-13  8.025
```

Based on the comment of Henrik, you can also transform to dates with:

```
dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date, '%Y_%m_%d')
```

Comment: Because "_Character strings are processed as far as necessary for the format specified: any trailing characters are ignored_", `as.Date("1979_8_9_0", format = "%Y_%m_%d")` is enough.

Comment: @Henrik That's very convenient. Didn't know that! Updated my answer to reflect that :-)

Comment: Thank you all for the help. :-)

Comment: @h3rm4n That and the "_Any character in the format string not part of a conversion specification is interpreted literally_" can save you from a lot of regexing/strspliting when parsing dates. `as.Date("Year: 1979, Month: 8, Day: 9, was a magic time", format = "Year: %Y, Month: %m, Day: %d")`

Comment: @h3rm4n, One of my data has too many missing values. I am encountering this error **Error in Summary.factor(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
Calls: aggregate ... aggregate.data.frame -> lapply -> FUN -> lapply -> Summary.factor
Execution halted**  I tried to add na.action=na.pass inside the aggregate function but it does not work. The same happens when I also add na.rm=TRUE before the na.action. Any suggestion to correct this?

Comment: @Lyndz If you include an example in your question that shows the problem, I can have a look at it. But if you read the error-message carefully, you can already see where the problem is: The variable you are trying to sum is not an integer / numeric variable. Converting it to numeric should solve it.

Comment: @h3rm4n. Thank you for the response. I asked this in a separate question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49023619/handling-nas-in-aggregate-function-in-r/49023724?noredirect=1#comment85053944_49023724) and was already solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
# split the "date" variable into new, separate variable
splitDate <- stringr::str_split_fixed(string = df$Date, pattern = "_", n = 4)

df$Day    <- splitDate[,3]


# split data by Day, loop over each split and add rain variable
unlist(lapply(split(df$Rain, df$Day), sum))
```