# Handling NA's in aggregate function in R

Tags: r, aggregate, na

I am trying to get the daily sum from a csv file using the aggregate function but I am encountering the following errors:

```
Error in Summary.factor(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), na.rm = FALSE) : ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
Calls: aggregate ... aggregate.data.frame -> lapply -> FUN -> lapply ->          Summary.factor 
Execution halted
```

Here is the link to the data [Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwu8m61b9k38y17/Laoag_tc_induced.csv?dl=0)

Here's my code:

```
dat<-read.csv("Laoag_tc_induced.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
dat[dat == -999] <- NA
dat[dat == -888] <- 0
dat$Date <- as.Date(strptime(dat$key, '%Y_%m_%d_%H'))

df <- data.frame(dat$Date,dat$RR,dat$dist)
df <- aggregate(RR ~ Date, dat,sum)

names(df)[1] <- "Date"
names(df)[2] <- "Rain"

write.table(df,file="test.csv",sep=",")
```

I tried using:

```
df <- aggregate(RR ~ Date, dat,sum,na.rm=TRUE)
```

and

```
df <- aggregate(RR ~ Date,dat,sum,na.rm=TRUE,na.action=na.pass)
```

The error is still the same:

```
‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certain elements in the 'RR' i.e.  `"   NA"`, changed the class of the column to `factor` (also use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`).  The option would be to specify the NA strings within `na.strings` to be read as `NA`

```
dat <- read.csv(file, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
          na.strings = "   NA", strip.white = TRUE)
```

After doing the OP's transformation/replacement,

```
res <- aggregate(RR ~ Date, dat,sum)
head(res, 5)
#        Date  RR
#1 1994-08-09 0.0
#2 1994-08-10 0.0
#3 1994-08-11 0.0
#4 1994-08-12 0.3
#5 1994-08-13 0.0
```

As the OP stated that the date are getting changed, it is working fine based on the data provided

```
dat[78:81,]
#   X.1          key     SN CY     Lat.x    Lon.x     X   RR     Lat.y    Lon.y     dist       Date
#78  78  1994_8_19_0 199419 19 0.3700098 2.230531 49133 28.8 0.3176499 2.104727 824.8680 1994-08-19
#79  79  1994_8_19_6 199419 19 0.3787364 2.214823 49134 28.8 0.3176499 2.104727 765.4631 1994-08-19
#80  80 1994_8_19_12 199419 19 0.3857178 2.200860 49135 28.8 0.3176499 2.104727 720.0335 1994-08-19
#81  81 1994_8_19_18 199419 19 0.3926991 2.190388 49136 28.8 0.3176499 2.104727 700.1729 1994-08-19
```

which is same as the one in the csv data

[image]

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I got a warning message: **NAs introduced by coercion**. I added your suggestion in reading the csv and added a this line: dat$RR<-as.numeric(dat$RR) and got the warning message

Comment: @Lyndz  I was using only the data you shared.  In that the NA is `"   NA"`   If it is only a subset of data, then check the entire data for any other string values other than numbers and specify that also in `na.strings`.

Comment: @Lyndz  I didn't get your warning message.  You can also use a package `dat <- readr::read_csv(file)` which did the conversion correctly by spotting the NA elements

Comment: The result is incorrect for some dates. For example, this line: **1994-08-19,230.4** which should be 1994-08-19,115.2 only. I dont know why the value is like this

Comment: @Lyndz  You need to check the 'key' column format `head(dat$key, 3)#
[1] "1994_8_9_0"  "1994_8_9_6"  "1994_8_9_12"` .  I don't know why you have year followed by three numbers.  When you convert to `Date` with `as.Date`, the format chosen is `'%Y_%m_%d'`.  So, what is the last number?

Comment: @Lyndz  key column values are in the same format based on the example you showed `all(stringr::str_count(dat$key, "_")==3)#
[1] TRUE`

Comment: The last number is hour. It should be like this: **dat$Date <- as.Date(strptime(dat$Date, '%Y_%m_%d_%H'))**. But the results are still incorrect.

Comment: @Lyndz  You should convert from the 'key' column which has the original format which you are trying to change. `dat$Date <- as.Date(strptime(dat$key, format = '%Y_%m_%d_%H'))` and I don't have a problem with this step `class(dat$Date)#
[1] "Date"`

Comment: I also did this,but the values are still incorrect. The values are incorrect starting in this line: 1994-08-19

Comment: @Lyndz  Not sure what values are incorrect.  I updated with the rows I got for `1994-08-19`.  It is basically the same format as in the 'key' without the 'hour'

Comment: row 78 to 81 in the original csv. The RR values are 28.8 in each 0,6,12,and 18hr

Comment: @Lyndz  It is what I got there

Comment: @Lyndz  I also posted the screenshot of the excel rows.  It is the same for me.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the first 20 rows in my terminal

Comment: @Lyndz  There are 8 rows for 1994-08-19.  You can check `library(dplyr);datS <- dat %>% filter(Date == "1994-08-19"); datS %>% pull(RR) %>% sum
[1] 230.4`

Comment: I also noticed it (dat[which(dat$Date == "1994-08-19"),]). Thank you so much for the help. Its the problem of my pre filtering.